# How can I use default MVC editor if i have defined editor template for particular type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I use default MVC editor if i have defined editor template for particular type?

For instance I have editor for string type("`string.cshtml`") in "Editors" folder. When I use

`@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyStringField)`

it uses my template("`string.cshtml`").
But I have area in my application and I want use there default MVC editor template for string type. Is it possible?

Comment: Try put this default template within your area views

Comment: Try passing an empty string as the second argument of EditorFor.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your editor template in folder Views\Shared\EditorTemplates in your area or in your root folder.

If you want, you can set editor template for current property:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyStringField, "editorTemplateName");
```

In this case you should name editor template custom name (not string).

Comment: Yes, I did it, I created "string.cshtml" file in that folder and by doing this I've overrided default MVC editor template for string type. But after that how can I use that overrided default MVC editor template. Everery time I use string field in @Html.EditorFor(..) it uses new custom template("string.cshtml") but not default. I need use both of them (custom and default) depends on situation. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use this overload to call named editortemplate: public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
 this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
 Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
 string templateName
)